# Select all timestamps that is between range in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp, date-range

I'm working on a calendar like feature to a project of mine.

I have a table like the following:

```
ID | Title             |Where     |tri| Start      | End        | tro
______________________________________________________________________
"4"|"Planingfrenzy"    |"Street 8"|"0"|"1395835200"|"1395846000"|"1"
"5"|"Other meeting"    |"Road 8"  |"0"|"1395140400"|"1395158400"|"1"
"6"|"Third meeting"    |"Lane 8"  |"0"|"1395819000"|"1395824400"|"1"
"8"|"Weekend at cyprus"|"Cyprus"  |"0"|"1395928800"|"1396162800"|"1"
```

I have a problem selecting alla events that happens in one day. 
I tried the following two queries, but they only return those events thats start and end at the same day.

```
/*
   Start is a unixtimestamp for the beginning of the day
   End is a unixtimestamp for the end of the day
*/

//This Returns to many events since all events that ends before the end timestamp is a match etc. 
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (start > ? OR end<?) 

//This matches all events that start and end at the same day. But a multi day event like "Weekend at cyprus" isn't returned since it is out of range
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (start > ? AND end<?)
```

Is there some way in MySQL or PHP to match if start/end range "touches" in the queried timestamp range?

Comment: What values are you using for `?`?

Comment: You want all the events that are on one defined day (i.e. all events that are on 7th march, 2015) or all events that only last one day?

Comment: @GordonLinoff As mentioned in the comment ? = is the first/last timestamp for the day.

Comment: @AndreschSerj i want all events thats on a certain date. eg: I have an event that begins 13.00 march 7th and ends 12.00 9th march. If I check for events on march 8th I still want that event to show up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the two values of `?` are the earliest and latest values in the day, I think you want:

```
where start < (?end) and end > (?start)
```

That is, there is an overlap when the start of one is before the end of the other, and vice versa.

In this answer `(?end)` is intended to be the last timestamp of the day and `(?start)` is intended to be the first.

Comment: Quite annoying that I didn't figure this out myself! Thanks, big time!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the correct expression is to use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE 1 AND date BETWEEN start AND end
```

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want to catch any event that has either a start time or an end time within your defined time range.

I didn't actually test on your dataset but this should get you headed in the right direction regardless:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE (Start >= :start AND Start < :end)
OR    (End >= :start AND End < :end)
```

And because you have included the PHP tag in your question, here is an easy way to get the "start" and "end" timestamps you need for a given date, in my example, I will use "today" as the target date.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$date = new DateTime('today', $timezone);

$start = $date->getTimestamp();
$end   = $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->getTimestamp();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: @Strawberry is it the SQL or timestamps that are bothering you? :)

Comment: @Strawberry, I think I get what you're saying, but Gordon's solution assumes that both the start and end time both fall within the desired range, while my solution assumes that *either* the start or end time fall within a given range. It also depends on how you calculate your start/end times, I just wanted to give an example that might get OP headed in the right direction.

Comment: No. Think about it. Draw a diagram if you like.